# Arrange MYSQL Data

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MYSQL DATA in TABLE

```
ID     Name     Quantity

1      Lemon    1
2      Lemon    5
3      Tomato   10
4      Tomato   15
5      Tomato   20
6      Potato   20
7      Potato   25
```

I want it display in HTML table like this:-

```
ID     Name     Quantity

1      Lemon    1KG + 5KG = 6KG
2      Tomato   10KG + 15KG + 20KG = 45KG
3      Potato   20KG + 25KG = 45KG
```

But i am not getting what i do. Please suggest if you have any good idea to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show the summation or do you really, really want that exact display showing x+y = total?

Comment: I want to show both, Quantities and there total sum.

Comment: ok, but you do realize that you have bought yourself a lot of grief by saving 25kg instead of just 25 right?

Comment: Yes. MYSQL data will be having only numbers. Like 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
 t.ID,
 t.Name,
 CONCAT(t.output,' = ', t.total,' KG') AS expression
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
   ID,
   Name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Quantity,' KG') SEPARATOR ' + ') AS output,
   SUM(Quantity) AS total
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY Name
) AS t;
```

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c27818/14/0)</kbd>

---

Through the inner query grab the expression of the left side of `=` operator and the summation of quantity separately.

Through the outer query prepare your desired expression using the inner query as a sub query.

---

**Note:**

Operation of this kind should be done in the application logic.